# Non-nested Rails Form with Multiple Entries and One Submit Button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms

Is it possible to have a non-nested form create multiple entries and then submit using one button? I need to iterate through a collection for form headings, but I'm trying to simplify and not nest the form.

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <%= form_tag(picks_path, method: :post) do %>

    <%= hidden_field_tag "picks[][user_id]", current_user %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "picks[][game_id]", current_game %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "picks[][category_id]", category.id %>

    <%= "Category: #{category.name}" %>

    <%= text_field_tag "picks[][:pick]" %>

  <%= submit_tag 'Submit Ballot' %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So far, this creates multiple submit buttons and only leaves the last entry in the params hash.

Example:

> "picks"=>[{"user_id"=>"1", "game_id"=>"1", "category_id"=>"2",
>   ":pick"=>"two"}]

Comment: I believe when you click 'submit' that it is making a call to the server once, and what you're looking to do is make several calls at once, or do a batch update. I'd suggest looking into batch updates, or you can accomplish this through AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the form tags outside the loop.